# how do i capture multiple "partners" of a string in perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a large multiline file to parse, which I have slurped into a single string in Perl. So it ends up like this:

```
my $string = "foo1 randomtext bar1 randomtext bar2 randomtext bar3/foo2 randomtext bar4 randomtext bar5 randomtext bar6 bar7/foo3 randomtext bar8 randomtext bar9/";
```

it consists of a set of records, each one with a header entry `(foo+number)` and each is separated by a symbol; `"/"` in this case.

I'm trying to capture the header info (foo) and some of the text further down in each entry (bar+number). in each case I would like to capture the header info paired with each instance of "bar" to maintain the specific foo and bar relationships within each entry.

I want the output to look like this:

```
foo1_bar1

foo1_bar2

foo1_bar3

foo2_bar4

foo2_bar5

foo2_bar6

foo2_bar7

foo3_bar8

foo3_bar9
```

I have tried various regex's, with combinations of `?` after the `.`+ to make it minimal rather than maximal, including matching the `\/` record separator after (bar\d) (which makes it only find the final bar of the record, rather than the first),

```
while ($string =~ m/(foo\d).+?(bar\d)+/g)
{
    print "$1_$2\n";
}
```

which returns

```
foo1_bar1

foo2_bar4

foo3_bar8
```

So just the first bar for each foo. Basically the `+` after the `(bar\d)` doesn't make this a multiple match and that's my problem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: please show the original structure of the data before slupring

Comment: foo1 hfgvkjsdhfjghnsdlkjfg   \n lkhdlkgalkdngf \n;ljfdlkhgnlkdfn \n     bar1 kjbfdgkjbadkjgbkajdfg \n kjbfdjgjadfg \n ljbdfjglnadfg bar2 ,jbdfjbadfjbd \n \n \n \n \n lhafdgklnaldfglkafd  bar3 lkandfglkhnadfgn \n \n ladfglhaf \n lknadfga /foo2 lahfeglkhaflgk        etc etc etc (you get the picture - couldn't do 'actual' carriage returns in comments box...)

Comment: As a comment, the global match working like you want and ignoring what's between and returning all foos with a trailing bar would give foo1_bar1, foo1_bar2, foo1_bar3, foo1_bar4, foo1_bar5... as the intermediate foos would get likewise ignored, still not giving the results you expect.

Comment: i wasn't making it deliberately hard - not sure where you are looking for capitalisation. and that was the best I could do for the file structure, as I can't do carriage returns in comments. maybe I should have put it as an edit in the original question? remember: first question - need help in even asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my approach is to split at "/", get the "foo" and then use a simple regex to catch the bar's:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

my $string = "foo1 randomtext bar1 randomtext bar2 randomtext bar3/foo2 randomtext bar4 randomtext bar5 randomtext bar6 bar7/foo3 randomtext bar8 randomtext bar9/";

foreach my $chunk (split(/\//,$string)) {
   (my $foo = $chunk) =~ s|.*(foo\d).*|$1|;
   while($chunk =~ m|(bar\d)|g) {
      print $foo . "_$1\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: however, can you tell me what this line is doing:  (my $foo = $chunk) =~ s|.*(foo\d).*|$1|;? thanks!

Comment: this line reads $chunk into $foo while on-the-fly modifying $foo's content with the replace-regex that extracts "foo\d" ($chunk is not modified, so we can use it the next line...)

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the string into the elements you're interested in, preserving order, than iterate over that array to build your pairs:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my $string = "foo1 randomtext bar1 randomtext bar2 randomtext bar3/foo2 randomtext bar4 randomtext bar5 randomtext bar6 bar7/foo3 randomtext bar8 randomtext bar9/";
my @elements;

while ($string =~ /((bar|foo)\d)/g) {
    push @elements, $1;
}

my @pairs;
my $currfoo;
for my $element (@elements) {
    if ($element =~ /foo/) {
        $currfoo = $element;
    }
    else {
        push @pairs, join '_', $currfoo, $element;
    }
}

p(@pairs);
```

Output:

```
[
    [0] "foo1_bar1",
    [1] "foo1_bar2",
    [2] "foo1_bar3",
    [3] "foo2_bar4",
    [4] "foo2_bar5",
    [5] "foo2_bar6",
    [6] "foo2_bar7",
    [7] "foo3_bar8",
    [8] "foo3_bar9"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to load the file into a giant `var`. And you can avoid complex regex.

```
begin read the file line-by-line info $line
    if $line == ^foo* then set foovar=$line
    else
      if $line == ^bar* then echo $foovar_$line
end
```

Comment: ah. thanks, @Dr._Tyrell. but in the real file, the randomtext 'filler' spans >1 line. so i use /msg modifiers after my regex for the slurped file. I can match the individual components with this (so I know it's slurped into a string properly).

Comment: i just thought of something... whether it would be easier to split the file (at he "/") into individual records and the work on each record (and just globally match all the foo's and then all the bar's. not pretty but it might work...

Comment: If you were able to cobble $string from a large pile of gunk, then you can probably just alter your data munging script to sit on each FOO until the next FOO comes along.<br/>

As long as the lines for "foo??" and "bar??" are on their own, then it doesn't matter how large the 'randomtext' .

Comment: bwahah, i didn't see Oeser's answer earlier, nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's tokenize and iterate:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use feature 'say';
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "foo1 randomtext bar1 randomtext bar2 randomtext bar3/foo2 randomtext bar4 randomtext bar5 randomtext bar6 bar7/foo3 randomtext bar8 randomtext bar9/";

my @foo;
my $tokenizer = make_tokenizer($string);

while (defined(my $token = $tokenizer->())) {
    if ($token =~ /\Afoo([0-9])\z/) {
        push @foo, [$1 => []];
    }
    elsif ($token =~ /\Abar([0-9])\z/) {
        push @{ $foo[-1][1] }, $1;
    }
}

for my $x ( @foo ) {
    my $foo = $x->[0];
    for my $bar ( @{ $x->[1] }) {
        say "foo${foo}_bar$bar";
    }
}

sub make_tokenizer {
    my $string = shift;
    sub {
        return unless length $string;
        my $token;
        ($token, $string) = split qr{[ /]}, $string, 2;
        $token;
    };
}
```